# convergence of altered sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, euler-mascheroni-constant

Let $x_n=(1+\frac{y}{n})^n$. It is well known that $x_n\rightarrow e^y$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Now, if we consider $X_n=\left(1+\frac{y}{n}+o(\frac{1}{n})\right)^n$, then it makes sense that $X_n\rightarrow e^y$, too, because $o(1/n)$ vanishes faster than $1/n$ as $n\rightarrow\infty.$ However, how can this be shown rigorously? Does this also hold more generally? I.e., if $f(1/n)\rightarrow z$, do we then also have $f(1/n+o(1/n))\rightarrow z$?

Comment: $(1+\frac{y}{n}+o(\frac{1}{n} ))^n\approx e^{y+n\cdot o(\frac{1}{n})}\to e^y$

Comment: I do not see how that helps. In addition, you let $n$ in $o(1/n)$ change only after you have already established convergence to $e^{y+no(1(n)}$.

Comment: @user90369 Your argument boils down to showing: let $y_n\rightarrow y$. Then $\left(1+\frac{y_n}{n} \right)^n\rightarrow e^{\lim y_n}=e^y$.

Comment: That's right. Please see the post of *Ivan Neretin*.

Comment: I am pretty sure, there are sequences such that $\lim_n y_n(k)$ exists for all $k$ but for which $\lim y_n(k_n)$ does not satisfy $\lim y_n(k_n)=\lim y_n(\lim k_n)$.

Comment: Yes, but here you have a special condition for $y_n$: $n\cdot o(1/n)\to 0$ means that $y:=\lim y_n$ exists. Therefore exists for every $\epsilon>0$ a $N$ so that $|y_n-y|<\epsilon$ for $n>N$ . This means too that for $|a-b|<\epsilon$ and $a<y_n<b$ for $n>N$, $|a|<N$, $|b|<N$ we have $(1+\frac{a}{n})^n<(1+\frac{y_n}{n})^n<(1+\frac{b}{n})^n$ and therefore $e^a<e^{\lim y}<e^b$ .

Comment: Yes, I think that argument makes it quite clear. Do you think this holds in more general settings, too? Such as $f(1/n)\rightarrow z$, does it imply $f(1/n+o(1/n))\rightarrow z$?

Comment: I think there is no different if you use $\frac{1}{n}\to 0$ or $\frac{1}{n}(1+n\cdot o(\frac{1}{n}))\to 0$. They are only two different sequences with the same limit and $f$ has to be defined for each argument.

Answer (score 0):

Well, $X_n=\left(1+\frac{y}{n}+o(\frac{1}{n})\right)^n=\left(1+\frac{y}{n}\right)^n\cdot\left(1+o(\frac{1}{n})\right)^n$, so its limit may be treated as a product of two limits which are both (supposedly) easy to find.

Comment: How can you write this as your product?

Comment: I can write anything as a product if I divide my anything by something and then multiply by that something.

Comment: I do not see how you changed the starting position of my question then. You replace one sequence that converges to $0$ by another

Comment: Let's put it this way: which proof of $(1+\frac{y}{n})^n\to e^y$ do you rely upon?

Comment: If possible, I'd rather not prove this from scratch (i.e., based on some unique proof of convergence to the exp function). Intuitively, it's clear that if $(1+y/n)^n \rightarrow e^y$, then the contribution of $1/n$ is much more important than that of, say, $1/n^2$, hence $(1+y/n+o(1/n))^n$ should have the same limit. Do you think this can be shown rigorously, also for other types of sequences similar to $X_n$?

Comment: You don't show things rigorously while standing on some intuitively clear foundation. Either you must have both things rigorous, or both things intuitive.

Comment: I think intuition is a good starting point, don't you?

Comment: Well, yeah, maybe... OK, how about that: since some position, $1+{y\over n}+o({1\over n})$ is strictly between $1+{y-0.01\over n}$ and $1+{y+0.01\over n}$, then a similar thing with 0.001, then 0.0001, and so on, so the limit must be...